# qsort.cpp not found (debug in Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I debug my code in VS 2017 and get message:
qsort.cpp not found

```
You need to find qsort.cpp to view the source for the current call stack frame
Original location: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdlib\qsort.cpp
Locating source for 'minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdlib\qsort.cpp'. Checksum: SHA256 {a4 7d 36 67 4b 4a f4 5c 68 59 42 17 a7 26 df b7 93 50 a6 d2 f5 76 aa ca cc d1 7 23 22 90 ee 76}
```

What i should do?

Comment: If this file exists then try a workaround: turn off the option "Options -> Debugging -> General -> Require source files to exactly match the original version".

Comment: Note: you may not have source for every C library function (and thus will not be able to debug *into* it).

Comment: I dont know, where this file should be is.

Comment: Where i can get source?

Comment: Do you know where is the button "Search" in Windows?

Comment: If there a reason you expect to get the source of the Visual Studio C run-time library? If you want that, use an open source compiler.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\ <VERSION> \ucrt\stdlib`

Comment: ***What i should do?*** When you debug don't try to step into the implementation of the run time unless you really need to debug how it is implemented.

Comment: Use std::sort ant not qsort.

Comment: why it's better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same issue as yours in my side like the follow screen shot, and then I click Browse and find qsort.cpp, browser this file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.15063.0\ucrt\stdlib, I could step into this cpp file normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why you should use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`

`std::sort` is in C++11 an O(NlgN) where qsort is unspecified.

std::sort may produce optimal code for the type its sorting due to inlining, qsort can only use your compare on void *.

`std::sort` is typesafe.

Tests suggest that `std::sort` is between 250% to 1000% faster than `qsort`.

Of course there are sorting algorithms that are even faster for special cases where you know the range of value for example is few discreet value you can get O(N).